# Which VIMEO API to use for our needs - web based help "tutorials"

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

We have a web based system that we are looking at replacing our existing "help system" from uploading flash videos directly to our website to instead "embedding" content we upload to our vimeo account. We have setup a vimeo pro account and these videos need to be "private" i.e. not accessible to the general public. Which API version should I use? And do you have any sample code in say PHP I could take a peek at with the functionality we are after

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced and Simple API's will no longer receive new features, and soon you will not be able to create new apps for them.

Vimeo has moved towards a unified API, which you can read about at http://developer.vimeo.com/api. Make sure to use the api through api.vimeo.com, not vimeo.com/api/rest/v2.

Vimeo has an official PHP library, with some very basic examples that you can see at http://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php